# What is the overlap between the Gaia and the Hipparcos catalog?

Tags: gaia, star-maps, hipparcos

Is there any kind of concordance available between the sources in the Hipparcos catalog and the Gaia DR2 catalog? I.e., mapping the Gaia DR2 source_id to the Hipparcos HIP number?

Comment: Do you want the mapping for an individual or small list of objects or for the whole Hipparcos catalog?  SIMBAD will do the former e.g. for [HD209458](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=HD+209458&submit=submit+id) and look under 'Identifiers'

Comment: This is probably unhelpful but the files in http://cdn.gea.esac.esa.int/Gaia/gdr1/tgas_source/csv/ (and files in similar directories) do this for GAIA DR1. Unfortunately, there is no corresponding directory for GAIA DR2: http://cdn.gea.esac.esa.int/Gaia/gdr2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As part of the Gaia DR2, cross-matches to several catalogues including HIP2 were included. The main reference for this is Marrese et al. (2018) "[Gaia Data Release 2. Cross-match with external catalogues: algorithms and results](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.09151)". The resultant matches are included in the tables `gaiadr2.hipparcos2_best_neighbour` and `gaiadr2.hipparcos2_neighbourhood` available via the query facilities in the [Gaia Archive](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/).

Unfortunately the match is not particularly complete and it is not entirely clear why. From the paper:

> While we expect to find Gaia counterparts for most of the Hipparcos2 sources, with the exception of the brightest ones, the
>   cross-match results include only about two-thirds of them. This
>   means that according to the adopted cross-match algorithm, only
>   about two-thirds of the Hipparcos2 objects have a Gaia counterpart that is compatible within the position errors (i.e. have at least
>   one good neighbour). Hence the Hipparcos2 cross-match results
>   clearly show an issue that needs to be investigated.

As a result, they also provide a table of cross-matches based on a 1-arcsecond cone search, available on the [Gaia DR2 known issues page](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/gaia/dr2-known-issues#CrossmatchHipparcos). This cross-match is a lot more complete, but there are still a few objects that are present in both catalogues that are missing. Several of these are nevertheless present in SIMBAD, e.g. [85 Pegasi](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=85%20Peg&submit=SIMBAD%20search) = HIP 171 = Gaia DR2 2853900872207150720.